# Semaphore - task to run faster with semaphore

Tags: c#, semaphore

My school task is to build a code with the same loop delay but using semaphore to run the task faster. This is for learning semaphore.
I have made the script as follows however the delay between two similar threads are 1.4 seconds. Is there a way by adjusting semaphore to make the program run faster.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

//Example in using sleep() and Threads in C#
namespace ThreadSys
{

    class ThreadClass
    {
        int loopDelay, loopCnt;
        Thread cThread;
        static Semaphore _sem = new Semaphore(1, 5);

        public ThreadClass(string name, int delay)
        {

            loopCnt = 0;
            loopDelay = delay;
            cThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run));
            cThread.Name = name;
            cThread.Start();


        }
        // The main function in the ThreadClass
        void run()
        {

            do

            {

                _sem.WaitOne();

                 Console.Write(cThread.Name + ":" + DateTime.Now.ToString(" HH:mm:ss.fff "));
                Console.Write(cThread.Name + ":" + " Hello  ");
                Console.Write(cThread.Name + ":" + " A number ");
                Console.Write(cThread.Name + ":" + " Year ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Thread.Sleep(loopDelay);
                loopCnt++;

                _sem.Release();


            } while (loopCnt < 40);


            Console.WriteLine(cThread.Name + "*Finished* ");

        }
    }
    // The application
    class ThreadSys
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            ThreadClass dt1 = new ThreadClass("[T1]", 95);
            ThreadClass dt2 = new ThreadClass("[T2]", 191);
            ThreadClass dt3 = new ThreadClass("[T3]", 287);
            ThreadClass dt4 = new ThreadClass("[T4]", 383);
            ThreadClass dt5 = new ThreadClass("[T5]", 479);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How sure are you that the program runs long enough for your threads to complete? Your `Main` method doesn't have a wait handle once your threads have started. This might terminate your threads prematurely since the program just ends after the last thread is created.

Comment: @Dandré thank you:-)